# “error: '_hypot' has not been declared in this scope” in function math.c in a C++ project

Tags: c++

- Mingw32 4.8.1
- Win 7 64bit
- Code::block 13.12 svn 10341 32bit
- wxWidgets 3.0.2

My project compiles nicely in Debug mode, but got this error in Release mode. I have quite a few library that I link to, cryptopp is one of them, it's a wxwindows based project, compiled with mingw, and working under Code::Blocks. It's not a python project, and I noticed a similar question that made use of python, I tried declaring

```
#include <cmath>
```

at the very beginning without much success.

The error points to math.h lines 633 to 636 which read as such:

```
#ifndef __NO_INLINE__
__CRT_INLINE float __cdecl hypotf (float x, float y)
{ return (float)(_hypot (x, y)); }
#endif
```

Comment: at least show code block around this "_hypot" that cause compilation error

Comment: and Code::Block is just editor, include information about os and compiler which you use

Comment: Please include some code if you want help...